# Rect Native. Использование ExpoKit в продакшн?

Tags: react-native

У expo.io классный набор инструментов.
И я бы хотел их использовать в разработке проектов, как своих так и на заказ, которые потом публикуются в Google Play и App Store.

Вопрос:
Можно ли без проблем использовать Expo SDK просто как набор готовых инструментов без привязки к сервисам expo и прочему?

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо выполнить команду **exp detach**, для вас будут подготовлены проекты для ios & android. Вы можете дополнить их другими нативными библиотеками для этих платформ, а также самостоятельно собирать и публиковать приложения в маркетах.

Концептуально это называется ExpoKit:

https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/detach.html#content

Есть свои за и против, подробно описано на странице по ссылке. Если кратко у вас остается возможность использовать библиотеки из sdk и дополнять и изменять нативный код. Из минусов вы лишаетесь легкости обновления до следующей версии сдк и expo-клиента и облачной сборки. Все это нужно делать "руками".